# How can I write a MySQL query for this database design?

Tags: php, mysql

### Task 1

First I have a specific user, I want to see with which user it is connected to. Let's say alex in following table. I want to check if alex is connected to another user? In following table it is connected with John and christina, so I select john and christina.

### Task 2

Now I have another user. Let's say martin, I want to see which of the previous selected users (john and christina) are connected with the martin.

```
ID  user1      user2   status
1   alex       john      1
2   john       martin    1
3   Jane       smith     1
4   smith      john      1
5   christina  alex      1
```

For example, in above table:

People who are connected to alex are john and christina. We want to check which of the users (john and christina) are connected with martin, and the result should be row2.

### Update

You all are mentioning that the database design is not good, can you please tell me what is wrong with it? Here is my user table:

Table 1, users

```
ID      username
```

and here is Table 2, user_connections

```
ConnectionID     user1_ID     user_Connectedto
```

Comment: That is called a bad database design...At least `user2` column should have been an ID of the `user1` column.

Comment: You need to review your design. This is awful to say the least. I'd try with one table containing your users, with another table to relate users to one another.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure your exact requirements but it would seem the database design you chose isn't really the best.

I think you would have wanted to go with a table with unique users. And then another table that links IDs of those users

```
--Users Table
ID     Name
1      Alex
2      John
3      Jane
...

--UserConnection Table
ID     ID_ConnectedTo
1      2
1      3
```

In this case, Alex is connected to John and Alex is connected to Jane.

Comment: My database design is exactly same like what Jooria mentioned in previous post. I have user table which has unique ID for each user. Second table is userconnections, which has user1, user2 and status (1 shows they are connected). Someone merged my post to the original post, can you tell if I should add double rows for each connection? or single is enough? like ID ID_ConnectedTo 1 2 2 1 1 3 3 1

Comment: For your purposes, I would be tempted to say that you should have "double rows for each connection". An example of this would be twitter where personA can follow personB and personB can follow personA but these follow actions are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you asked for, for you current schema:

```
SELECT user2 FROM
(SELECT user1, user2 FROM connections
UNION
SELECT user2, user1 FROM connections) t
WHERE user1 = 'martin'
```

You should consider the idea that "john connected with alex" isn't the same as "alex connected with john". If this is something like facebook, where a person has to allow a connection, then you'll want to build the connections both ways. If the connection is only in one direction, it means that the connection hasn't been approved by the other party yet.

Please review more normalized database designs suggested by other users.

Comment: It mean if alex dont want to be any more connected, it can disconnect however john will be still connected to alex. I wanted that if any of the user decide not to be anymore connected, the relationship is broken, and for that purpose i thought previous approach would be better.
Please give me some idea about the database design. Thanks.
(PS. Theres another table "users" which has ID for each user)

Answer (score 0):

firstly it would indeed be better to structure as SAGExSDX suggests...

to find any relationship:

```
SELECT * from connections where user1 = X OR user2 = X
```

Replace X with the username you need - or better the userID if you do refactor AS SAGExSDX suggests

Comment: my database design is exactly like you mentioned. Of course i have users table where each user has a unique ID. UserConnection table has ConnectionID, user1_ID, user2_ID connection_status (1 or 0)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the code isn't the best, but if you want a query which will grab double links, you'll have to be careful about the direction as mentioned by Marcus. It takes four distinct queries (joined with a union) using the table structure you describe:

```
SELECT user2 FROM connections
WHERE user1 IN (
    SELECT user2 FROM connections
    WHERE user1 = 'alex'
)
UNION
SELECT user1 FROM connections
WHERE user2 IN (
    SELECT user1 FROM connections
    WHERE user2 = 'alex'
)
UNION 
SELECT user1 FROM connections
WHERE user2 IN (
    SELECT user2 FROM connections
    WHERE user1 = 'alex'
)
AND user1 <> 'alex'
UNION
SELECT user2 FROM connections
WHERE user1 IN (
    SELECT user1 FROM connections
    WHERE user2 = 'alex'
)
AND user2 <> 'alex'
```